flask-sqlalchemy delete row not succeed?
I use flask-sqlalchemy as my orm. And I have a post_file request needs to response immediately. Thus, I use multiprocessing to forward the request to post_file_async. Here I need to delete some rows. However, I've discovered a bug that's not very easy to reproduce. In about 2~3 of my 10 requests, the delete method not work. The printed length of the query before and after delete is the same.
import multiprocessing
import os
import requests
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from .models import InfoModel

app = Flask(__name__)
mysql_user = os.getenv("MYSQL_USER", "root")
mysql_password = os.getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD", "root")
mysql_host = os.getenv("MYSQL_USER", "127.0.0.1")
mysql_port = os.getenv("MYSQL_PORT", 3306)
mysql_db = os.getenv("MYSQL_USER", "test")
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s' % (
    mysql_user, mysql_password, mysql_host,
    mysql_port, mysql_db)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route('/post_file_async', methods=['POST'])
def post_endpoint():
    data = request.json
    form_id = data["form_id"]
    old_query_list = db.session.query(InfoModel).filter(
        InfoModel.form_id == form_id,
    ).all()
    print('===len query_list:{}===='.format(len(old_query_list)))
    db.session.query(InfoModel).filter(
        InfoModel.form_id == form_id,
    ).delete()
    db.session.commit()
    new_query_list = db.session.query(InfoModel).filter(
        InfoModel.form_id == form_id,
    ).all()
    print('===len query_list:{}===='.format(len(new_query_list)))
    return jsonify({"message": "success"}), 200


def time_consuming_operation(request_data):
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:5001/post_file_sync"
    requests.request("POST", url, json=request_data)


@app.route('/post_file', methods=['POST'])
def post_endpoint():
    data = request.json
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=time_consuming_operation,
                                      args=(data,))
    process.start()
    return jsonify({"message": "success"}), 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Anyone knows what is wrong with this? Thanks in advance.
